# Canvas line jump

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm learning new python. I'm trying to design a chatbot. I've added the codes I've made so far. I want the distance between the bubbles to remain constant in long articles. Can you help with this? I'm sorry about my bad English.[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
import random
import re
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.font import Font
import textwrap

root = Tk()
root.config(bg="lightblue")
root.geometry('410x600+400+100')

#ana ekran
canvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200,bg="white")
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
canvas.place(x=10, y=10, width=390, height=530)


balon = []

class balon1:
    def __init__(self,master,message=""):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(master,bg="light green")
        self.i = self.master.create_window(30,490,window=self.frame, anchor="sw")       
        Label(self.frame,text=datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %X"),font=("Helvetica", 7),bg="light green").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w",padx=5) #tarih saat        
        Label(self.frame, text=textwrap.fill(message, 35), font=("Helvetica", 9),bg="light green").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w",padx=5,pady=3)
        root.update_idletasks()
        self.master.create_polygon(self.draw_triangle(self.i), fill="light green", outline="light green")

    def draw_triangle(self,widget):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.master.bbox(widget)
        return x1, y2 - 10, x1 - 15, y2 + 10, x1, y2

def send_message():
    if balon:
        canvas.move(ALL, 0, -70) 
    a = balon1(canvas,message=entry.get())
    balon.append(a)

#mesaj yazma alanı
entry = Entry(root,width=26, font=("Helvetica", 10))
entry.place(x=10, y=550, width=290, height=40)

#buton
buton = Button(root, width=10, height=2, relief='raised',state='active',command=send_message)
buton.config(text='GÖNDER', bg='lightblue', font='Verdana 8 bold')
buton.place(x=310, y=550)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing would be to start by creating the bubble and then getting the height of the bubble. Then, move everything up by that amount plus a margin, and then move the bubble to where it belongs.

Even easier might be to simply add the new bubble under the current bubble and then scrolling everything up so that it is in view.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to write a sample code that shows how I can do it? I will be grateful if you could help me.